# How to run a shell command in the calling (current) shell with Java

Tags: java, shell, cd

Suppose something like this:

```
execInCurrentShell("cd /")
System.out.println("Ran command : cd /")
```

is in the `main()` function of `MyClass`

So that when I run the class, I `cd` into the `/` directory

```sh
user@comp [~] pwd
/Users/user
user@comp [~] java MyClass
Ran command : cd /
user@comp [/] pwd
/
```

The usual way to run shell commands, that is, through the `Runtime` class:

```java
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cd /")
```

Won't work here because it doesn't run the command in the current shell but in a new shell.

What would the `execInCurrentShell()` function (the one that actually works) look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to run commands that affect the current invoking shell, only to run command line bash/cmd as sub-process from Java and send them commands as follows. I would not recommend this approach:

```
String[] cmd = new String[] { "/bin/bash" }; // "CMD.EXE"
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);

Path out = Path.of(cmd[0]+"-stdout.log");
Path err = Path.of(cmd[0]+"-stderr.log");
pb.redirectOutput(out.toFile());
pb.redirectError(err.toFile());

Process p = pb.start();
String lineSep = System.lineSeparator(); 

try(PrintStream stdin = new PrintStream(p.getOutputStream(), true))
{
    stdin.print("pwd");
    stdin.print(lineSep);
    stdin.print("cd ..");
    stdin.print(lineSep);
    stdin.print("pwd");
    stdin.print(lineSep);
};
p.waitFor();
System.out.println("OUTPUT:"+Files.readString(out));
System.out.println("ERROR WAS: "+Files.readString(err));
```

}

This also works for CMD.EXE on Windows (with different commands). To capture the response per command you should replace use of `pb.redirectOutput()` with code to read pb.getInputStream() if you really need the responses per line rather than as one file.

Comment: Okay. I guess I'll have to use substitution like this then: `cd $(java MyClass)`

Answer (score -1):

On Windows to start a command shell from Java program, you can do it as follows:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Command {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

You need to use the same approach for Linux.

Comment: The question is not about starting a command shell. Also, this would not execute it in the current shell anyways (as already mentioned in the question).